# How do WordPress plugins work with oAuth2 APIs?

Tags: plugin-development, api, oauth

I am having trouble with getting the redirect part of an oAuth2 authentication process to work correctly within a WordPress plugin. Mainly, the query string that WordPress uses for settings pages is conflicting with the query string that the API tries to return.

**An explanation:**

I'm using the Avvo API (http://avvo.github.io/api-doc/) in a custom Wordpress plugin; this plugin has a settings page. Wordpress uses a query string to determine which settings page is being viewed.

For example, the URI of my plugin's settings page is

```
http://localhost:8888/dmr/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=kp_avvo
```

This settings page is also what I want to use as the redirect_uri for the oAuth2 token request. However when I click the redirect link that Avvo returns (returned via a cURL request), it doesn't take into account the fact that the URI already has a query string. It adds another ? when it adds the "code" and "access_token" query string parameters.

For example, it tries to take me back to

```
http://localhost:8888/dmr/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=kp_avvo?code=420582y5evzb9y84y20c0chm6#access_token=2p39dng5wsyubvxpb47ohdo7x
```

*(note the double ?s)*

The API added its own query string on top of the existing one. I'm sure having two ?s in the URI is invalid already, but WordPress especially doesn't like it - it just shows an error screen, which means I can't retrieve the "code" and "access_token" parameters.

**My questions:**

Is this how oAuth2 inherently works? That is, is it even possible to use a redirect URI that already has a query string with oAuth2?

Or is this possibly a bug in Avvo's implementation where it just tacks on a new query string, instead of adding parameters to an existing query string?

Comment: Are you controlling the output of the redirect link? It looks like you could send `http://localhost:8888/dmr/wp-admin/options-general.php` as the `redirect_uri`, and then before outputting the link, append the `page=kp_avvo` by using `add_query_arg()`

Comment: I can control the output of `http://localhost:8888/dmr/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=kp_avvo` as much as the Settings API allows. I created that page with `add_options_page( 'KP Avvo', 'KP Avvo', 'manage_options', 'kp_avvo', 'kp_avvo_options_page' );` But I think you might be on to something, I'm gonna try that.

Comment: That didn't quite work. When I click through to the oAuth2 authentication process, I can't control the redirect URI after that point. After authenticating the app it sends me to `http://localhost:8888/dmr/wp-admin/options-general.php?code=17djg#access_token=e7f83`. But in order to retrieve those $_GET parameters I'd need to check for them in a more general action for the admin area, like `admin_init` or something. I'd like to keep it all contained to my custom options page if possible.